# To prove that Cantor function is not absolute continuous, do we need to take countable infinite number of subintervals?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity, cantor-set

[This highly upvoted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125345/why-is-the-cantor-function-not-absolutely-continuous) claims that we can show that the Cantor function is not absolute continuous by taking a finite number of subintervals. However, one comment right below the answer claims that the "answer" is incorrect (insufficient) because based on Royden, we need to take countable infinite number of subintervals. The original text of Royden is attached here. I am not sure if the comment is correct. What is the complete proof?

[image]

Comment: Royden's sums are finite. For $\epsilon=1$ he shows there is no $\delta$ for which the condition for abs continuity holds. That is, for each $\delta>0$ there is an $n$ such that $(2/3)^n<\delta$, and now with this  $n$ fixed, note that the sum on the left is $< \delta$ and yet the sum on the right is not <$\epsilon.$

Comment: I have another doubt here: Towards the end, (in the attached picture), how do they get that $ \sum_{1 \le k \le 2^n}[ \phi(d_k) - \phi(c_k) ] = 1 $ ?
I don't see how this is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment is incorrect.  The Cantor set can indeed be covered by finite unions of open intervals with arbitrarily small total length, as Elchanan Solomon explained in his response to the comment.

In detail, the Cantor set $C$ is defined as the intersection of a sequence of sets $C_n$, where each $C_n$ is a finite union of closed intervals of total length $(2/3)^n$.  Taking slightly larger open intervals around each of these closed intervals, we can find a finite union of open intervals $U$ which contains $C_n$ and has total length at most $(2/3)^n+\epsilon$ for any given $\epsilon>0$.  Taking $n$ to be large enough and $\epsilon$ to be small enough, $(2/3)^n+\epsilon$ will be smaller than any given $\delta>0$.  Thus for any $\delta>0$, there exists a finite union of open intervals $U$ containing $C$ with total length less than $\delta$.

Alternatively, following the argument in Royden that you attached yourself, you can actually just use the interior of $C_n$ as your open intervals.  These open intervals don't quite cover $C$, but they are still good enough to prove the Cantor function is not absolutely continuous, since the Cantor function is still constant on each component of their complement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So let $n$ be a finite number, is the "n-stage Cantor function" corresponded to the $C_n$ cantor set absolutely continuous or not? I once thought that we can only show that the limit point (the actual Cantor function) is not absolutely continuous, which means we need countably infinite number of sets to cover that.

Comment: I don't know how you're defining the "$n$-stage Cantor function".  If it's piecewise linear and continuous, then it is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Can the n -stage Cantor function be defined exactly same as the one in the second page of the picture attached?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "exactly the same".

Answer (score 4):

The commenter in the link you gave was confused. Absolute continuity only trades in finite collections of intervals, not infinite ones. In fact, the answer in the link is exactly the same as in royden.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After a few pages the Royden book actually tell us the it is equivalent to definite the absolute continuity by replacing the word "finite" to "countably infinite"

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  What the linked comment claims is that the Cantor set cannot be covered by finitely many intervals with arbitrarily small total length.  If that were correct, it would mean that the proof is wrong (using the definition of absolute continuity that involves only finite collectinos of intervals).